# Attempting to add multiple records to MYSQL using form

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms, pdo

I have a form which allows a user to add a new course title and gives them the option to add more record making it more convenient instead of submitting each one separately.

I've attempted to use syntax which I've seen in a number of examples online and it works in adding extra rows dynamically however this affects the form submission when it connects to the mysql database.

It will add the first record however not the second and I'm not sure if I'm executing it correctly using PDO.

if anyone could provide some insight as to how i can achieve this and why my code is failing i would be much appreciative.

the php file:

```
<?php

include "db_conx.php";

try
{
    $db_conx = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);

    $db_conx->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = $db_conx->prepare("INSERT INTO `insights`.`course_details` (`course_title`) VALUES (:course_title)");

    $course_title = $_POST['course_title'];
        //$course_code = $_POST['course_code'];

    $sql->bindParam(':course_title', $course_title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        //$sql->bindParam(':course_code', $course_code, PDO::PARAM_STR);


    /*** execute the prepared statement ***/

    $courses = array();
    if ($sql->execute()) {
            $courses[] = $sql;
        }
    }

    /*** success message ***/


    $message = "<p class='text-success'> Record Successfully Added <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'/></p>";
} 
catch(Exception $e)
{
    $message = 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}


die($message);
?>
```

the AJAX which adds more rows when clicked and submits the form when 'submit' is clicked:

```
function addCall() {
  var data = $('#addForm').serialize();
  $.post('ManageCourses_AddSubmit.php', data, function(response){

    $("#addForm").html(response);
    //'soft'reload parent page, after a delay to show message
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('#addModal').modal('hide')
      location.reload();
    },3500);

  }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
  });
}

jQuery(function($){
    var i = 1;
    var $button = $('#add_row'),
        $row = $('.addForm').clone();

    $button.click(function(){
        $row.clone().insertBefore( $button );
    });
});
```

the form where the data is sent from:

```
                <div class="modal fade" id="addModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Add New Record: </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <form id="addForm" class="addForm">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="course_code" class="pull-left" class="control-label">Course Code:</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="course_code_id" name="code[]" readonly value ="NULL">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="course_name" class="pull-left" class="control-label">Course Title:</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Course Title" id="course_title_id" name="course_title">
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <div class="btn-toolbar">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add_row" name="add_row">Add New Record <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="del_row" name="del_row">Delete Row <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" class="pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" class="pull-right" onclick="addCall();">Submit <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-saved"></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

thank you! :)

Comment: what is the function of $courses array in your php code ?

Comment: i was trying to store each course_title given in the form into the courses and execute it as an array inserting each one by one

Comment: I am sure if that approach will work like that. Additionally are you sure that the values are getting passed to your php code via POST ?

Comment: The first value is getting passed so it successfully adds the first value stored in the form but it ignores the second which is why I'm confused

Comment: Try adding echo $message at the end of your php code and try again ? (in try part of the php code)

Comment: just tried and I'm getting errors saying '
Fatal error: Cannot use try without catch or finally in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/insights/ManageCourses_AddSubmit.php on line 28'

Comment: would you say my code is okay or is there a better way to handle this multiple array?

Comment: I think you are adding die($message) at the end which might be causing problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is coming from targeting an element id in the following line:

`var data = $('#addForm').serialize();`

First off, you should always treat the id attribute as if it only exists in one location of the DOM. For more information, see:

http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute

To fix your problem, you need to pass the data from each element and handle the data differently on the backend. In your JavaScript, change the following line:

`var data = $('#addForm').serialize();`

to:

```
var data = {};
var index = 0;
// use the class of the form elements instead
$('.addForm').each(function(){
  // take each form value an store it within the data variable
  data['course_code'][index] = $(this).find('input[name=course_code]').val();
  data['course_title'][index] = $(this).find('input[name=course_title]').val();
  index++;
});
```

Now, you need to update your backend to accept the new array of values...

```
<?php

include "db_conx.php";

try
{
    $db_conx = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);

    $db_conx->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $courses = array();
    // check if we have valid post data
    if(isset($_POST['course_code']) && isset($_POST['course_title']))
    {
      foreach($_POST['course_code'] as $index=>$course_code)
      {
        // check if we have a matching title (needed for the title insert)
        $course_title = '';
        if(isset($_POST['course_title'][$index]))
          $course_title = $_POST['course_title'][$index];
        else
          continue; // no title found, skip to the next index

        // at this point, use $course_title and $course_code in your query
        $sql = $db_conx->prepare("INSERT INTO `insights`.`course_details` (`course_title`, `course_code`) VALUES (:course_title, :course_code)");

        $sql->bindParam(':course_title', $course_title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sql->bindParam(':course_code', $course_code, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        /*** execute the prepared statement ***/
        if ($sql->execute()) {
          $courses[] = $sql;
        }
      }
    }

    /*** success message ***/


    $message = "<p class='text-success'> Records Successfully Added <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'/></p>";
} 
catch(Exception $e)
{
    $message = 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}


die($message);
?>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help. i have updated the code to try however the submit button no longer works in calling the jQuery when more than one value is provided. However when i just give it th one value it works in submitting but the MYSQL database does not get updated

Comment: I added validation for the input data, so make sure you insert both fields correctly. You can remove the `isset()` statements if you dont want this, but they are good to have around.

Comment: Actually, I had a typo. I used course_name instead of course_title in the first if statement. Try it now.

Comment: unfortunately it still does not work. the submit button doesn't submit the data :/ really confused why its being like this. is my approach correct in submitting the form multiple times? or is there a cleaner way to get it to 'add' another row to the form and submit the additional info?

Comment: Post the error messages you're getting within the JavaScript and/or PHP.